# sending email times out

Tags: meteor, mailgun

Trying to send an email keeps giving me timeout errors:

> Exception while invoking method 'sendEmail' Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

The `MAIL_URL` variable is set like this in a `server/lib` folder:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var user = "username@sandbox************.mailgun.org",
    pass = "***********",
    host = "smtp.mailgun.org",
    port = 25,
    url = "smtp://" + user + ":" + pass + "@" + host + ":" + port + "/";

  process.env.MAIL_URL = url;
});
```

Comment: Are you running this from home? Most ISP's don't allow outgoing SMTP connections.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I changed to use port 465 and now it works, so you might be right! who knows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ISP is most likely blocking `port 25` to prevent you from sending spam. See [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404564/checking-your-outgoing-mail-server-(is-port-25-blocked)) for reference. Something else like `587` will do. See this [example](https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-meteor-sendgrid/).